# mysql or php comparing names

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one with all the correct names of people in it, and then I have a table with all the correct names plus a bunch of names where there is some kind of misspell in the name, or using other characters.

For example, we got a name like Henry Muller, and then one with Henry Müller or Henry Mueller, and many other variations like that.

Is there some kind of mysql function that can compare those names to match 90% of the characters or something similiar? I know I cant match all the names to the correct ones, but I am hoping to get some of the way.

Its in a mysql database - but wouldnt mind getting the job done in php.

Thanks a whole bunch:)

Comment: You can use regex but that doesn't work well with indexes on very large tables. You could also use the LIKE '%blabla%' for example which would be faster but might give you wrong results. If you know a pattern of how the names are misspelled that would help but other than that, no there is no function that magically will fix the names.

Comment: Have you looked into the MySQL `LIKE` operator? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: You may want to check `http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php`

Comment: The metric you probably want to use is Levenshtein distance.  You can google "MySQL Levenshtein distance" for an implementation in MySQL.  One caution, though:  the comparisons can be relatively slow if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction - cool functions those similar text and levenshteins distance:) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this will accomplish what you're after, but you'll have to deal with the possibility of false matches

```
SELECT A.name, B.name
  FROM TABLE_A A
       INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
          ON Soundex(A.name) = Soundex(B.name)
```